# Getting DeadSystemException from WorkManager on LG Android 10 devices

Tags: android, android-workmanager, android-10.0

I am getting following RuntimeException from Crashlytics.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to create service androidx.work.impl.background.systemjob.SystemJobService: java.lang.RuntimeException: android.os.DeadSystemException
```

It happens 100% on Android 10 (so far)
[image]

And 100% on LG devices (Especially on LG K50) (so far)
[image]

The WorkManager version I am using is 2.4.0

Does anyone have an idea?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/DeadSystemException

It would be helpful to get more information. How many instances are you getting of this particular error?

Comment: Last 90 days ~5000 crashes from 56 users. The trend of crashes are going up recently.

Comment: You can open an issue to have the team investigate  on this, but they'll need more information...
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=409906&template=1094197

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://issuetracker.google.com/u/0/issues/173766925

It seems to be a LG manufacturer bug. There may be nothing you can do from the App developer/WorkManager side.